How long would it take to exhaust integers up to MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?
I found that searching for this answer confusing and not well documented.
In JavaScript you have a MAX_SAFE_INTEGER defined as 2^53 - 1
I did discover an article that put such large numbers into perspective however they focus on 2^64. And JS uses a smaller number. Most birthday paradox calculators lack the ability to scale to that number.
Why is this interesting? I found myself debating with developers about the use of a UUID(v4) for unique IDs in their web apps. By comparison a monotonic counter globally used in a single web app would have an entire 2^53 - 1 space of unique values per tab session. I'm interested in understanding the trade off of the exhaustion of values for a monotonic counter compared to the collision probability of UUIDv4.
Adding Context
This thought experiment came about from an exercise in generating unique IDs for a web application. The intent of these unique IDs was so components within the app when mounted/rendered could have a unique ID for that instance that they could then use in things like <label for=…> and <input id=…>.
Much of the assumptions for the team when they needed a unique ID they would generate a Version 4 (random) UUID.
Since these were to guarantee uniqueness it got me thinking that perhaps instead of relying on the improbable nature of finding a collision in the UUID space within our lifetimes to guarantee uniqueness that instead a form of a monotonic counter (clock) would be far easier to have the same guarantees.
const uniqueId = ((id) => () => ++id)(0);

This lead me to wonder what the worst case scenario was for a web application to exhaust the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER space of values. And to compare it to the UUID space exhaustion and possible collision (birthday paradox).
And lastly why use randomness (however large the space is) instead of a monotonic counter for uniqueness in this scenario.

You could use BigInt instead of an integer... You will not have a limit, but your script loses a little efficiency though... There's more... If your script generates a UUID at each second (and never takes less time or generate more than one UUID), then your UUID could just be Date.now().

"… however they focus on 2^64." - so just divide their results by 2^11 (=2048) and you got your results.

"confusing and not well documented" - what was confusing you? You just have to divide the size of the search space by the speed of your search. What speed you assume depends a lot on your concrete constraints and assumptions - if you want us to solve them, you'll need to provide more details.

The calculation to find the time to exhaust MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (in years) should be pretty straightforward if we assume we're working with a monotonic counter that increments once per second.

Calculate MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (2^53 - 1) =  9,007,199,254,740,991
Divide that by the number of seconds in a year (this only works
assuming the counter increments once per second), which would be
~31,536,000 seconds. So, 9,007,199,254,740,991 / 31,536,000 =
285,616,414.7 years to exhaust.


The Sun will die in about 5 billion years. So we can cycle through this about 20 times.

Frame challenge
You are not really taking in the big picture.
Out of idle curiosity, I tried to figure out what is the collision chance after generating 2^53 - 1 UUIDs. But then I thought about it a bit more: if you really have that many UUIDs, are you not doing something incorrectly?
Some back of the napkin maths:
2^53 - 1 = 9 007 199 254 740 991

9 trillion UUIDs
Each UUID is 128 bits1, so
9 007 199 254 740 991 * 128 = 1 152 921 504 606 846 800

One quintillion bits. In bytes
1 152 921 504 606 846 800 / 8 = 144 115 188 075 855 860

144 quadrillion bytes. In kilobytes:
144 115 188 075 855 860 / 1000 = 144 115 188 075 855.84

144 trillion kilobytes. In megabytes:
144 115 188 075 855.84 / 1000 = 144 115 188 075.85583

144 billion. In gigabytes:
144 115 188 075.85583 / 1000 = 144 115 188.07585583

144 million. In terabytes:
144 115 188.07585583 / 1000 = 144 115.18807585583

144 thousand terabytes. In petabytes:
144 115.18807585583 / 1000 = 144.11518807585583

144 petabytes. That must be stored by the page. If they were not stored (say, you take one item, process it, give it an ID, then stop working with it) then there would be no issue with collisions. This is simply unfeasable amount of memory.
Let us say that you do not generate 2^53 - 1 UUIDs. Perhaps you only do half (72 petabytes), or a quarter of it (36 petabytes). That is still within the petabyte range. Way too large for any page.
We could look at it from the opposite direction - given some amount of memory how many UUIDs can we fit in it, which we can calculate by dividing the bytes by 16 (128 bits * 8  to get bytes). If we go with a whole lot memory for a single page 10 GB (10 000 000 000 bytes) we get:
10 000 000 000 = 625 000 000

625 million UUIDs. It is still a lot of memory to consume. And let us compare how that number compares to Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER:
9 007 199 254 740 991
          625 000 000

It is almost half the length.
I think all of these numbers really just show that if you ever have to consider UUID vs Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - then do not. It is not worth it, UUID is unfeasable at that point.
1 128 bits in raw form. As a string, it would be larger. But using the bits for easier calculation. Also, I assume it is UUID v4 as the most widely used one.
